# Adding callback as a parameter in scala?

Tags: scala

I have the below function in scala:

```
 def addAllCosts(costs: List[Int],discount: Int => Int): Int = {
var sum = 0
costs.foreach(sum += _)
discount(sum)
}
```

I am invoking the function like so in a http akka router:

```
HttpResponse(200, entity= repository.addAllCosts(costs,repository.applyDiscount(23)))
```

applyDiscount looks like this:

```
def applyDiscount(sum:Int): Int = {
    return sum - discount
  }
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error:(45, 94) type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Int => Int
```

Not sure how to resolve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applyDiscount` is an `Int => Int` function, however, you're passing `repository.applyDiscount(23)` as the value of the `discount` argument, and that expression has the type `Int` (because it's the result of *applying* the function to the value `23`), instead of the expected type `Int => Int`.

Not sure where the value 23 comes from, but this should at least compile of you just pass a reference to the method without applying it:

```
HttpResponse(200, entity= repository.addAllCosts(costs, repository.applyDiscount))
```